# Problem with returning querystring from Linkedin for Auth using Codeigniter 2.0.3

Tags: codeigniter, linkedin-api, codeigniter-2

Firstly, I am running CI 2.0.3.  Using good ol' google, it wasn't difficult to find code to achieve my current problem.  I have found these sources, but they have been written using 1.7.2:

> http://www.sudhircodes.com/main/codeigniter/status-update-to-linkedin/
>   http://blog.justni.com/posting-to-linkedin-from-php-and-codeigniter/

I am able to hit linkedin, put in my user credentials for authorising the application.

I get this back:

> http://www.domain.com/auth/linkedin_auth?oauth_token=ffdd1d7f-29a3-423c-ada7-a85d31bec080&oauth_verifier=97677

But the problem is if in the config:  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Then a 302 occurs and gets turned into http://www.domain.com/auth/linkedin_auth  No oauth_token.

If you then have $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';  No 302 occurs, so the querystring is intact, instead I get "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters"

No problem, just change $config['permitted_uri_chars'] right?  Wrong, I change it and even set it to blank and I just get an HTTP loop where it keeps on hitting /auth/linkedin_auth.

So has anyone managed to get CI 2.0.3 play nice with linkedin?  I'm slowly going bald! :p

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll marked this as answered.

I've gone back and tried with a new install of CI.  It works.  So there must be a gremlin somewhere else in my code :(

Edit: Found out that the Twitter library from Elliot Haughin manages to intercept the querystring when a twitter & linkedin or anysite returns back oauth_token or oauth_verifier to yours when doing an auth.  So I've had to come up with my own CI class extending the one from Tijs Verkoyen.

Comment: Make sure you let Elliot know about this on the GitHub page.

Comment: There is an already issue (although explained in broken english), but the project doesn't seem to be maintained any more.